# Get text after visual transformation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

Is there any way to get text after applying visualTransformtaion from text field in Compose?
`onTextChange` and `onValueChange` return the input before visual transformations

I checked the docs and found inside `CoreTextField`  that this transformation is setting into state by `TextFieldState` and `TextDelegate`. But I couldn't see any callbacks to get this changes back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the same `filter` used by the `VisualTransformation`

```
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val visualTransformation = MyVisualTransformation()

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation

    )

    val transformedText = remember(text, visualTransformation) {
        visualTransformation.filter(AnnotatedString(text))
    }.text.text
```